# How to map with a conditional in Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm traversing through an object array:

```
people = [
  {id:1, name:"Bob", available:false},
  {id:2, name:"Sally", available:true},
  {id:1, name:"Trish", available:false},
]
```

I want my output to be the names of those available:

```
["Sally"]
```

I currently know how to map and extract for a field. 
How do I add the conditional?

```
  const peopleAvailable = people.map(person => person.value);
```

Want to do something like this:

```
  const peopleAvailable = people.map(person.available => person.value);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot conditionally map with the `.map()` function alone, however you can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve what you require.

Calling filter will return a new array where each item in the new array satisfies your filtering criteria (ie `people.available === true`).

In the case of your code, you can directly chain filter with your existing call to `.map()` to obtain the desired result:

```js
const people = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Bob",
    available: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Sally",
    available: true
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Trish",
    available: false
  },
];

const peopleAvailable = people
.filter(people => people.available)    /* filter available people */
.map(person => person.name)            /* map each person to name */ 

console.log(peopleAvailable);
```

Comment: I'm trying to filter by available, would this be correct?  const peopleAvailable = people.map(person => person.value).filter(person => person.available);

Comment: @NinaScholz think you're seeing an old edit - accidental "tab enter"

Comment: this makes sense. Thanks. Does .filter(people => people.available) also work? Wondering if I need to add the "===" for that boolean conditional

Comment: @lost9123193 yes you can ommit the `=== true` in this case.I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
people.reduce((a,c) => a.concat(c.available ? c.name:[]), [])
```

```js
people = [
  {id:1, name:"Bob", available:false},
  {id:2, name:"Sally", available:true},
  {id:1, name:"Trish", available:false},
];

let r = people.reduce((a,c) => a.concat(c.available ? c.name:[]), [])

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the condition in `map()`. If you put conditions then other elements will be returns as `undefined`. You can deal with this by applying `filter()` which allows you to return only those elements which are falls in your condition. So you need to use `filter()` then use `map()` on the filtered result.

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Bob",
    available: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Sally",
    available: true
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Trish",
    available: false
  },
];

const withFilter = array
.filter((r) => { return r.available; })
.map((m) => { return m.name; });                

console.log(withFilter);

const withOutFilter = array
.map((m) => { if(m.available) { return m.name; } });                

console.log(withOutFilter);
```